# openshift set env jdk8

Tags: java, variables, tomcat, openshift

I have 2 Cartridges on openshift platform

- Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)
- PostgreSQL 9.2

I have also precompiled war file i want to deploy in the weapps/ directory in my openshift git repository (pushed into remote server).

Problem is war file is compiled to run in 1.8jre and the default jre is 1.7

I created simple executable shell script named start in repo in directory

`.openshift/action_hooks/`

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

But still after restart app `rhc app-restart myApp` system variable JAVA_HOME is set back to jdk7.

Could you please point me out where is the problem?

Comment: What script have you placed this in?

Comment: Alternatives is a Linux mechanism with its own small command set. `http://tech.lanesnotes.com/2008/03/using-alternatives-in-linux-to-use.html`

Comment: @JoopEggen I was under impression that all system variables should be set via openshift tools or openshift variables 

`\> alternatives --config java`
`admindir /var/lib/alternatives invalid`

Comment: You evidently are right.

Answer (score 0):

The script you are using is correct and must work. In the action_hooks/start script, add below lines.

```
#!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
echo $(java -version)
echo 'Starting application...'
```

You must see java 8. Anytime you start your application it should be same.